# Converting user input into a symbolic variable for a matrix

Tags: matlab

I am making a program that obtains user input for helping to solve static problems however I have run into a bit of a dilemma.
The problems require that the user input a set of nodes per component and then either create a separate vector for the specific component, or use the nodes to create a quadratic formula, take the derivative then append it to a main matrix. Right now I am using a for loop and I don't know how to name a vector based on the ith value or take the user's input and create a symbolic variable from it.

Here is the part of the code that is being problematic:

```
N = sym('a', k_number + 1);
for n = 1 : k_number %goes from 1 to the number inputted by the user
fprintf('Please enter the two nodes attached to spring %d\n', n) %requires the nodal number attached to the spring
num1 = input(''); %gets the first node value
num2 = input(''); %gets the second node value
N(n, num1) = sym('u%d%d', n, num1); %Suppose to replace value in N matrix with unique symbolic variable
N(n, num2) = sym('u%d%d', n, num2); %Suppose to replace value in N matrix with unique symbolic variable
end;
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sym`.  Use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) instead.  This will symbolically substitute variables in your symbolic matrix with another expression.  I'm going to assume that `num1` and `num2` will choose two unique columns in your particular symbolic matrix per row.  Therefore, do something like this:

```
N = sym('a', k_number + 1);
for n = 1 : k_number %goes from 1 to the number inputted by the user
    fprintf('\nPlease enter the two nodes attached to spring %d\n', n) %requires the nodal number attached to the spring
    num1 = input(''); %gets the first node value
    num2 = input(''); %gets the second node value
    old_var1 = ['a' num2str(n) '_' num2str(num1)]; %// CHANGE
    old_var2 = ['a' num2str(n) '_' num2str(num2)];
    new_var1 = ['u' old_var1(2:end)];
    new_var2 = ['u' old_var2(2:end)];
    N = subs(N, old_var1, new_var1); %// CHANGE
    N = subs(N, old_var2, new_var2); 
end
```

What the above code will do is that for each row in your matrix, we get two unique column numbers.  We then extract the variables from these two columns per row, and change them from `ax_y` to `ux_y`.  On my machine, when I create `N`, this is what I get when `k_number = 4`:

```
N =

[ a1_1, a1_2, a1_3, a1_4, a1_5]
[ a2_1, a2_2, a2_3, a2_4, a2_5]
[ a3_1, a3_2, a3_3, a3_4, a3_5]
[ a4_1, a4_2, a4_3, a4_4, a4_5]
[ a5_1, a5_2, a5_3, a5_4, a5_5]
```

The row and column numbers are separated by a `_` character.  Now, let's go through the above code.  The majority of it is the same, but what has changed is that we are going to create 4 new strings.  Two of them are going to create those strings that correspond to the variable you want replaced.  That's what `old_var1` and `old_var2` are doing.  The next two are going to be those strings that correspond to the new variable you want inserted, corresponding to `new_var1` and `new_var2`.  If I understand your problem correctly, the variables need to change from `a` to `u`.  We finally use `subs` to substitute this particular value into the matrix to replace those variables.  Bear in mind that `subs` will return **the entire expression**, and so there is no need to assign to the output for a particular location in `N`.  As such, we re-assign the output back to `N` so it'll keep updating.

With the above code, here's an example run:

```
Please enter the two nodes attached to spring 1
1
2

Please enter the two nodes attached to spring 2
3
4

Please enter the two nodes attached to spring 3
1
5

Please enter the two nodes attached to spring 4
2
3
```

This was `N` after I ran the code:

```
N =

[ u1_1, u1_2, a1_3, a1_4, a1_5]
[ a2_1, a2_2, u2_3, u2_4, a2_5]
[ u3_1, a3_2, a3_3, a3_4, u3_5]
[ a4_1, u4_2, u4_3, a4_4, a4_5]
[ a5_1, a5_2, a5_3, a5_4, a5_5]
```

As you can see, those columns for each row were replaced by their corresponding columns read in from the user.  For each of those columns, the variables were replaced from `a` to `u`.  You don't seem to be updating the last row, but I suppose that is one of the constraints of what you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you very much! The design of the program requirements got changed a little so I will have to try this next time I run into the problem.

Comment: @GregFreisinger - No problem.  Didn't know where you disappeared to as I answered your question quite quickly with no reply. lol.  Well, if you do run the program and if this does do what you're looking for, consider accepting my answer.  Good luck!